Receiving a 404 Resource Not Found error when trying to use a stored procedure in PowerApps
I am trying to call a stored procedure in PowerApps, but I keep getting an error

{ statusCode: 404, message: "Resource not found" }

There really doesn't seem to be any information on this error that I could find, likely because the feature is so new.
The connection to the SQL Server itself works fine. I am using it in other places in PowerApps to retrieve data without hitting the 404 error.
Here is the code:
Table(SqlStoredProc.dboGetStructureCosts({ProjectID: DataCardValue1_2.Text, 
            Stage: StageField.Selected.Value, Version: VersionField.Selected.Value, 
            Type: TypeField.Text}).ResultSets.Table1)

I tried recreating the stored procedure connection without any luck. I saw somewhere that they had this problem and just had to wait an hour for the stored procedure to propagate, and I left it for the weekend. I've tried to make the call in different ways using ClearCollect or wrapping it in a Table().

I've had this problem starting just this week. Everything seems fine, and I know the app is indeed connected to SQL Server because intellisense picks up the name of the parameter the SP requires. But I get the "Resource not found" error.
I did notice that it's listing the connection differently. Before -- and those older apps are working fine -- it showed as the SQL database name, but now it shows as SQL Server: the call used to be to DatabaseName.schemaspname, but now it's SQLServer.schemaspname. So something appears to have changed lately, and that change seems to have broken something. (I tried changing the same of the data connection to the database name rather than SQLServer, without luck.)
UPDATE: I looked at the data via Monitor and found this line in the failed Network call:
 "request": {
      "url": "https://msmanaged-na.azure-apim.net/apim/sql/[longIDhere]/v2/datasets/,/procedures/power.uspGrandCentral",

Right after datasets is /,/  In the older, working app, the text between these slashes are the URL of our SQL instance and SQL database name, separated by the comma. I'm guessing that's why we get the "Resource not found" error. I don't know where this is set, but clearly something is missing in the action of adding the SP to the app.
